# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly": In Podfile:EXFirebaseCore (from../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`)

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.7",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.0.11",
    "@sentry/react-native": "3.1.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.6.1",
    "agora-react-native-rtm": "^1.5.0",
    "agora-rn-uikit": "3.1.3",
    "axios": "0.27.2",
    "dotenv": "10.0.0",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "4.2.1",
    "expo-auth-session": "3.6.1",
    "expo-checkbox": "^2.2.0",
    "expo-device": "^4.3.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "10.2.1",
    "expo-facebook": "^12.2.0",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^2.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "13.1.1",
    "expo-random": "12.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "^0.14.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "10.2.1",
    "firebase": "^9.11.0",
    "graphql": "16.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-agora": "3.7.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1289.0",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "2.5.4",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.2.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.8.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "3.11.1",
    "react-native-svg": "13.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "9.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.18.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "redux": "4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "sentry-expo": "4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```